# LFD wont start in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, services

Error messages:

> service lfd status Status of lfd:lfd is stopped
>
> tail /var/log/lfd.log Nov 24 15:36:05 lfd[3833]: Error Invalid configuration line, at line 64 Nov 24 15:36:05 lfd[3833]: daemon stopped

I've seen /etc/lfd.conf and it's ok, I've commented at line 64, but there is still an error.

What another file I must to review?

Answer (score 3):

For other people who might be seeking for same question and didn't got the answer.

Check the lfd log

```
# tail -f /var/log/lfd.log
```

You will find the answer there.

In some of the cases lfd won't start because it might be in testing mode.

Change following in `/etc/csf/csf.conf`

```
TESTING = "1"
```

to

```
TESTING = "0"
```

Answer (score 1):

just got this on my own server today. Figured I'd help.

As far as I can tell, the error is generated by the below foreach:

**File; /usr/sbin/lfd**

```
%configsetting;
foreach my $line (slurp("/etc/csf/csf.conf")) {
        $line =~ s/$cleanreg//g;
        if ($line =~ /^(\s|\#|$)/) {next}
        my ($name,$value) = split (/=/,$line,2);
        $name =~ s/\s//g;
        if ($value =~ /\"(.*)\"/) {
                $value = $1;
        } else {
             *Line 64* ---> &cleanup(__LINE__,"*Error* Invalid configuration line");
        }
    if ($configsetting{$name}) {&cleanup(__LINE__,"*Error* Setting $name is repeated in /etc/csf/csf.conf -$
        $config{$name} = $value;
        $configsetting{$name} = 1;
}
```

So, we can see line 64 " &cleanup(**LINE**,"*Error* Invalid configuration line"); " is thrown when the foreach/if statement logic is given a false.

For each line in /etc/csf/csf.conf, it will do some check, then report if it fails. What I don't get is why it's not giving us the exact line in the /etc/csf/csf.conf that is problematic. I checked line 54 of the csf.conf, and it's just fine - --

```
# Allow incoming PING
Line 64 --> ICMP_IN = "1"
```

I've removed it, and still "line 64" is the issue.

**Well, guess what works?** Just replacing the csf.conf with a new one from the installation package and redoing any edits you've done manually: http://www.configserver.com/free/csf.tgz

*sigh*